# Behavior of stem(x) with complex x

Tags: matlab, plot

Trying to [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19942552/fourier-transform-getting-mag-phase-then-using-those-to-plot-original-signal/19942987#19942987) a recent question I've come across a strange behavior with `stem`. Try this:

```
x = [1+j 2-j 3+j 4-j];
stem(x)
```

On my Matlab version (2010b) this plots the *imaginary* part of `x`, not the real part as I expected. On the contrary,

```
stem(1:length(x),x)
```

plots the *real* part of `x`, which is consistent with the behavior of `plot(1:length(x),x)`.

Can you think of any reason why `stem(x)` plots the imaginary part of `x` instead of the real part? Specially when `stem(1:length(x),x)` does plot the real part. Or should we conclude it's a bug?

Comment: Just mentioning `stairs` has the same behaviour as `stem`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this is partially correct behavior.  When you input an imaginary, the real and imaginary components are treated as x and y value pairs (i.e. in `xychk.m`, `x = real(y); y = imag(y);`).  So this explains why the imaginary component is on the y-axis.

However, when you input x-axis values with a second argument, it gets the x-axis values from the first input argument and treats the real part of `y` as the y-axis data.  Specifically, when `stem(1:length(x),x)` is called, `stem.m` creates a `specgraph.stemseries` with complex values provided for `YData`. However, it seems that the `YData` cannot hold complex data and the real part is kept. This feels like a bug, but it appears to be by design if the `plot` docs apply to `stem`.

As [stated by MathWorks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/plotting-imaginary-and-complex-data.html) about the `plot` command (apparently applies to `stem`):

> When the arguments to plot are complex (i.e., the imaginary part is nonzero), All MATLAB® graphics functions ignore the imaginary part except when plot is given a single complex data argument. For this special case, the command produces a plot of the real part versus the imaginary part. Therefore,
>
> `plot(Z)`
>
> where Z is a complex vector or matrix, is equivalent to
>
> `plot(real(Z),imag(Z))`

**There does appear to be a bug** in `stem` and `stairs` pointed out by David and Daniel R., where the proper `XData` is not set with the first (single-argument) syntax.  The source of the bug in `stem.m` seems to be here:

```
if hasXData
    xdata = {'XData', datachk(x(:,k))};
end
```

The problem is that `hasXData` is set above by `hasXData = nargs ~= 1;`.  I think this should perhaps be something like:

```
hasXData = nargs ~= 1 || ~isreal(args{1});
```

Comment: But if you do `x = [1+j 2-j 3+j 10-j];` then the x-axis points are 1, 2, 3 and 4, not 1, 2, 3 and 10, and `stem(x)` produces a different graph to `stem(real(x),imag(x))`.

Comment: For `stem([1+i,3,5-i])` it returns a plot with `(1,1)(2,0)(3,-1)`

Comment: @David (and Daniel R.) Interesting observations.  I'd agree that is a bug and I made a guess as to where it comes from in `stem.m`.  Still, it seems clear why the imaginary component ends up on the y-axis in the single-input syntax.

Comment: @chappjc Of course! How didn'y I think about it? `plot(x)` with `x` complex also plots imag vs. real. Lesson learned: don't choose too simple things such as 1:4 as examples