# How to combine the phase of one image and magnitude of different image?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, fft

I have two images `I` and `J`, I take `X=fft(I)` and `Y=fft(J)` to have the Fourier transforms, then I take the phase and magnitude of 'X' and 'Y' respectively.

The problem is I need to combine the phase of `X` and magnitude of `Y` to form a new image, and use `ifft` to reconstruct this new image, How to do that in MATLAB ?

Comment: What do you mean by "combine"?

Comment: I can only advice to invest significant time in the DFT. Anyway, you can combine like this:

`abs(F_x).*exp(i*angle(F_Y));` where `F_x` is the FFT of X

Comment: Take a look at this topic [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393257/getting-fourier-transform-from-phase-and-magnitude-matlab), I think they ask the same as you. They do only the recover with one image but you can use the real and imaginary parts from different images

Answer (score 7):

The magnitude and phase of the 2D Fourier spectrum can be expressed as the phase and absolute value of a complex number. For images in Matlab, it consist of a 2D complex array. You can create a 2D complex array merging the magnitude and phase like this:

```
FreqDomain = abs(Y).*exp(i*angle(X));
```

and feed it back into `ifft2`.

Note: use `fft2` to calculate 2D FFTs of images.

**Edit:** in fact there is a full example of exactly what you are asking on this page: http://matlabgeeks.com/tips-tutorials/how-to-do-a-2-d-fourier-transform-in-matlab/