# Matlab: Fourier Transform After changing phase matrix

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix, fft, ifft

I am working on some signals project and all I want to do is apply the fourier transform on a signal, get **magnitude** and **phases** and then change the **phase** matrix to something else say **phasenew** and then get the signal from **magnitude** and **phasenew**.

I am basing my code on [Getting Fourier Transform from Phase and Magnitude - Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393257/getting-fourier-transform-from-phase-and-magnitude-matlab)

```
>> F = fft(x);
>> mag =  abs(F);
>> phase = angle(F);
% Calculate phasenew using some algorithm, phasenew is very similar to phase, so output should be same.
>> re = mag .* cos(phasenew);
>> im = mag .* sin(phasenew);
>> F_i = complex(re,im);
>> x_i = ifft(F_i);
```

The output signal **x_i** is very different.

I found the similar problem here also : [Fourier Transform: getting mag + phase then using those to plot original signal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19942552/fourier-transform-getting-mag-phase-then-using-those-to-plot-original-signal/19942908?noredirect=1#comment42462736_19942908) but in this link, I commented on the answer to ask @David about how should I proceed to solve the case of phasenew. He suggested me to ask this as a new question so here it is.

Please help me to generate the signal using *inverse fourier transform* from **original magnitudes** and **new phases**.
Thanks in advance.

P.S. In **phasenew** I just shift the **phase** by either π/2 or -π/2.

Comment: Btw. If you just shift the phase by a constant it's the same as multiplying the original input with a fixed complex constant.

Answer (score 0):

For me your approach works:

```
x = rand(100, 1);
y = fft(x);
mag = abs(y);
phase = angle(y);
y2 = mag .* (cos(phase) + 1i * sin(phase));
y3 = complex(mag .* cos(phase), mag .* sin(phase));
sum(abs(y-y2).^2)
sum(abs(y-y3).^2)
x2 = ifft(y2);
x3 = ifft(y3);
sum(abs(x - x2).^2)
sum(abs(x - x3).^2)
```

Gives values in the order of 1e-30, so all compared signals (y, y2, y3) and (x, x2, x3) are identical except for tiny numerical deviations.

Comment: What is the use of sum function?

Comment: @Jerky To get the summed deviation of two signals. assert(y==y2) will fail but only by a tiny fraction. Up to numerical uncertainties the compared values are the same.